# making a trim method in a open fortran-90 statement don't work

Tags: fortran

In this subroutine I try to set dynamic names. The *filename* save the complete string . However, the *file* in the open statement doesn't have the string; '_1809.dat'.

```
subroutine db_write_matrix(dim,V,name)
    implicit none
    integer :: dim
    real(8) :: V(dim,dim)
    Character(len = 40) :: name
    Character(len = 60) :: filename
    integer :: i,j,u

    filename=trim('db_data/db_'//name//'_1809.dat')
    open(newunit=u, file=filename)
        . . .
    close(u)
    return
end subroutine db_write_matrix
```

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] forr all Fortran questions and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution, put

```
Character(len = *) :: name
Character(len = *) :: filename

filename='db_data/db_'//trim(name)//'_'//'1809.dat'
```

instead of the previously code